# Make Sure that Object Element Has Page Fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Object Element Which I Use To Load External Page On Click With a Button
My Html Is :

```
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<button onclick="getdata();return false;">Load page</button>
<div>
    <object type="text/html" id="ExternalPageLoader" data="#">
    </object>
</div>
```

And Script

```
<script>
function getdata() {
    var url = $("#txt").val();
    $("#ExternalPageLoader").attr("data", url);
}
</script>
```

How Can I Make Sure That Requested Page Has Been Fully Loaded Into Object Element 
i Would Like To Check The External Page Not the Current Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use with [`onload`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) .

```js
function getdata() {
        var url = $("#txt").val();
        $("#ExternalPageLoader").attr("data", url);
         console.log('loading...')
    }
    
    function loading(){
    console.log('loaded sucess')
    
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
  <button onclick="getdata();return false;">Load page</button>
  <div>
    <object type="text/html" id="ExternalPageLoader" data="" onload="loading()">
    </object>
   </div>
```

Comment: If the OP is using jQuery, could they not use `.on('load', func)`? As this would allow the function to not be global.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) event:

```
$("#ExternalPageLoader").ready(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Comment: This method has been removed from jQuery... it was deprecated in v1.8 and completely removed from v3.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about this.

Comment: yea it worked but as @evolutionxbox it has been deprecated so it wont be useful check the previous answer it works too